# Exception when processing form request despite 200 status

Tags: django, reactjs, forms, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a separate Django REST-api for my ReactJS app. I'm calling a fetch POST API to my endpoint to sign up users. I'm not sure what the error means since I'm getting a status of 200.

My Terminal traceback:

```
[30/Jan/2019 10:09:27] "OPTIONS /newuser/ HTTP/1.1" 200 108
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64666)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 651, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 721, in __init__
self.handle()
  File "/Users/shiningsunnyday/Documents/GitHub/kvizo_core/web/quizkly_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/shiningsunnyday/Documents/GitHub/kvizo_core/web/quizkly_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

My ReactJS code:

```
var csrftoken = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('value');
    console.log(csrftoken);
fetch('http://localhost:8000/newuser/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
  }),
}).then(
  (response) => {
    console.log("We did it!");
    console.log(response.json);
  }
).catch(
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

My Django view code:

```
class SignUp(APIView):

parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def post(self, request, format = None):

    print(request.data, " is request data")
    if 'username' not in request.data or 'password' not in request.data:
        raise ParseError('Username or password not provided')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        login(request, user)
        returnData = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(returnData.data)

    if 'username' not in request.data or 'password' not in request.data:
        raise ParseError('Username or password not provided')

    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']
    print(username, password)

    user = User.objects.create_user(username = username, password = password)

    login(request, user)
    returnData = UserSerializer(user)
    print(returnData.data)
    return Response(returnData.data)
```

The response callback should receive returnData.data, but instead returns a TypeError in console.

Answer (score 4):

Error `[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer` means that loading resource (in this example, ajax response) was interrupted, but not because of server fault. This means that either connection was broken or client interrupted loading of that resource.

In your case it can mean that either there is something wrong with your JavaScript code or with browser itself. Check network tab in browser debugger to find that interrupted connection, that should help to trace it down.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd set a premature timeout on my API client.